# Is toothpaste in plasma state?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

My friend told that toothpaste is an example for plasma state and it is because it is a semi solid.He said all semi solids are plasma

Comment: Your friend is, to put it mildly, about as wrong as [this guy](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/000/144/wrong05.jpg), only worse. Also, welcome to Chem.SE.

Comment: @NilayGhosh Disagree. It's closely related, but that question nowhere asks about plasma.

Comment: @hBy2Py  the plasma theory of  toothpaste is described in the comment section of the question.

Comment: @NilayGhosh But it doesn't show up in the *question*. If Simon-Nail-It had included it in the question body itself, then I would agree it deserves closure as a duplicate. But, comments are second-class content on SE sites, and so IMO the 'plasma' aspect doesn't count when considering whether the question is duplicative. <shrug> I'm fine with it if the community votes to close; I just would disagree.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Is irony and analogy allowed in comments? But nice reply though. I think this questions is flawed and must be flagged.

Answer (score 10):

**This is categorically false.**

I would consider toothpaste to be a highly viscous example of either a [non-Newtonian fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Newtonian_fluid) or a [colloidal suspension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colloid).

On the other hand, [plasmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)) exist as a mixed cloud of separated positive and negative [ions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion#Anions_and_cations), in many cases at [extremely high temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)#Temperatures).

One would need extensive dental work after attempting to brush one's teeth with a plasma.

Comment: I agree. But whether it's a non-Newtonian fluid or a colloid suspension really depends on the brand.

Comment: @orlandomarinella Yep, whether it's the paste type or the gel type.

Comment: It was an attempt at humor. No problem!

Comment: @orlandomarinella The content of your humorous addition was consistent with my intent, but I would prefer it to stand as originally written.  We may be up against a debate about paste- versus gel-type toothpastes, however: I would argue that [gel-type](https://maidsailors.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/gel-toothpaste-ms.jpg) is the non-Newtonian fluid, whereas [paste-type](http://nativewomenveterans.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/toothpaste.jpg) is the colloidal suspension.

Comment: Perhaps, although it, again, depends on the exact formulation of the gel or paste. For example, in my drawer over here, I do have a gel toothpaste with the strange fleck-y bits, along with lumps of what's probably whitening abrasive.

Comment: To be perfectly honest, they're probably a little bit of both, for each.

Comment: @orlandomarinella <nod>, it's not an either-or category distinction. As such, no offense, but I think I will actually just roll back to my original answer.

Comment: No problem at all, actually.

Answer (score 1):

**Absolutely wrong...!**

This is absolutely wrong, toothpastes are not in plasma state.
so what are toothpastes?
A simple answer is; toothpastes are either pastes or gels.
They are not solution because solute is not dissolved in the solvent. They are not suspensions because of ultra-high cocentration.
So toothpastes are emulsions (two phased mixture). Toothpastes comprise an oil-water emulsion. And this form is used to stabilize the primary components of the toothpaste.

- ***antiseptic/bacteriocidal component:*** this is contained in the aqueous phase of low viscosity it is capable of penetrating into the hollows of the teeth and gaps in the gums.
- ***hydrogen peroxide*** part which is stabilized in the hydrophobic part of the emulsion.

Read [Colloids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colloid) and [Emulsions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulsion) for better understanding.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. For more information in general have a look at the [help].